# Is there an ANSI SQL alternative to the MYSQL LIMIT keyword?

Tags: mysql, database, keyword, ansi-sql

Is there an ANSI SQL alternative to the MYSQL LIMIT keyword?

The LIMIT keyword limits the number of rows returned by a SELECT e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age > 18 LIMIT 2;
```

returns 2 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age > 18 LIMIT 10, 2;
```

returns 2 rows after the first 10.

Comment: Um... Those of us who know Ansi SQL may be able to help you if you told us what the MySql LIMIT keyword did...

Comment: James, SELECT * FROM table LIMIT x returns the first x results, and SELECT * FROM table LIMIT x, y returns y results with an offset of x.

Comment: @Aistina: Huh. I didn't know the LIMIT x, y version -- very handy!

Comment: Anyone know if which database abstraction layers support this and which do not (and for which DBs)?  Answer for any language...

Comment: LIMIT [x, ]y also works on Postgres.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the LIMIT x, y form still has to go over all the earlier rows, so it's not usually much faster than the other syntax (and can still be very slow for high limits).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How universal is the LIMIT statement in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528604/how-universal-is-the-limit-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[this shows the different ways:](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,4515,4678)

```
-- DB2
select * from table fetch first 10 rows only 
-- Informix 
select first 10 * from table 
-- Microsoft SQL Server and Access 
select top 10 * from table 
-- MySQL and PostgreSQL 
select * from table limit 10 
-- Oracle 
select * from (select * from table) where rownum <= 10
```

Comment: I've always thought it was ridiculous that Oracle makes you do a subselect to do it this way, but the rownum property is assigned prior to reordering with ORDER BY.

Comment: 'oraclese' has its pros and cons eh?  I do like Oracle's join shorthand (+) for an outer join...

Comment: +1 nice summary! SQLite supports LIMIT, like MySQL/PostgreSQL. InterBase/Firebird support SELECT FIRST and SKIP, like Informix.

Answer (score 27):

Not in SQL:1999.

There are two possible approaches you can use in later standards, with generally low levels of support in today's DBMSs.

In SQL:2008 you can use the DB/2 syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM things
ORDER BY smell
FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY
```

This only works for “LIMIT n” and not the extended “LIMIT m, n” offset syntax. In SQL:2003 you can use window functions, which can support the extended syntax but is a super PITA:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY smell) AS rn,
    FROM things
)
WHERE rn<=n -- or rn BETWEEN m+1 AND m+n
```

You will more usually use the DBMS-specific methods today.

Answer (score 15):

see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause

```
SELECT * FROM T LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 -- Netezza, MySQL, PostgreSQL (also supports the standard, since version 8.4), SQLite, HSQLDB, H2

SELECT * from T WHERE ROWNUM <= 10 -- Oracle (also supports the standard, since Oracle8i)

SELECT FIRST 10 * from T -- Ingres

SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM T order by a -- Informix

SELECT SKIP 20 FIRST 10 * FROM T order by c, d -- Informix (row numbers are filtered after order by is evaluated. SKIP clause was introduced in a v10.00.xC4 fixpack)

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM T -- MS SQL Server, Sybase ASE, MS Access

SELECT TOP 10 START AT 20 * FROM T -- Sybase SQL Anywhere (also supports the standard, since version 9.0.1)

SELECT FIRST 10 SKIP 20 * FROM T -- Interbase, Firebird

SELECT * FROM T ROWS 20 TO 30 -- Firebird (since version 2.1)

SELECT * FROM T
WHERE ID_T > 10 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY -- DB2

SELECT * FROM T
WHERE ID_T > 20 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY -- DB2 (new rows are filtered after comparing with key column of table T)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe so.  All the databases that I'm aware of use vendor-specific keywords for that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @jle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword/595155#595155):

- SQLite supports `LIMIT` (MySQL/PostgreSQL)
- InterBase/Firebird support `SELECT FIRST` and `SKIP` (like Informix)

Also see [Emulate MySQL LIMIT clause in Microsoft SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000)

Answer (score 1):

HSQL/H2 uses LIMIT like MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Let me link here a related SO question, with a [great answer by Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046664/558008) and another [good answer by bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528705/558008):

[How universal is the LIMIT statement in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528604/how-universal-is-the-limit-statement-in-sql)

*edit:* A few more good reference links, worth to look at in similar cases:

- [Wikipedia on limiting results and `FETCH FIRST` in the `SELECT` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause) ;
- ["Comparison of Different SQL Implementations" on limiting the result sets](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit) ;
- [The jOOQ user manual page on the `LIMIT` clause](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/) from [Lukas Eder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046664/558008).