# SQLAlchemy query to return only n results?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have been googling and reading through the SQLAlchemy documentation but haven't found what I am looking for.

I am looking for a function in SQLAlchemy that limits the number of results returned by a query to a certain number, for example: 5? Something like `first()` or `all()`.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

for `sqlalchemy >= 1.0.13`
Use the [limit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit) method.

```
query(Model).filter(something).limit(5).all()
```

Comment: I prefer this method over the others mentioned, is leaner since the extra data isn't passed over the network...

Comment: Is `.all()` really necessary ? Because it works without it.

Comment: If you want to index into the result like `results[2]`, `.all()` is necessary.  If you're just iterating over the results, I think leaving it off returns an iterator, so it's not necessary in that case.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative syntax

```
query.(Model).filter(something)[:5].all()
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy==1.1.15, raise: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: Use this query : query.(Model).filter(something).limit(5)
It works fine in SQLAlchemy==1.1.15

Comment: If you do [:5] I think the database would still pull all of the results and then you'd only use the last 5. Definitely better to use limit to prevent the database from returning extra data.

Answer (score 5):

If you need it for pagination you can do like this:

```
query = db.session.query(Table1, Table2, ...).filter(...)

if page_size is not None:
   query = query.limit(page_size)
if page is not None:
   query = query.offset(page*page_size)
query = query.all()
```

Or if you query one table and have a model for it you can:

```
query = (Model.query(...).filter(...))
                   .paginate(page=start, per_page=size))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since v1.4, SQLAlchemy core's [select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select) function provides a [fetch](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=fetch#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.fetch) method for RDBMS that support `FETCH` clauses*.  `FETCH` was defined in the SQL 2008 standard to provide a consistent way to request a partial result, as `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` is [not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1528604/5320906).

Example:

```py
# As with limit queries, it's usually sensible to order
# the results to ensure results are consistent.
q = select(tbl).order_by(tbl.c.id).fetch(10)

# Offset is supported, but it is inefficient for large resultsets.
q_with_offset = select(tbl).order_by(tbl.c.id).offset(10).fetch(10)

# A suitable where clause may be more efficient
q = (select(tbl)
       .where(tbl.c.id > max_id_from_previous_query)
       .order_by(tbl.c.id)
       .fetch(10)
)
```

The syntax is supported in the ORM layer since v1.4.38.  It is only supported for 2.0-style select on models; the legacy `session.query` syntax does not support it.

```py
q = select(Model).order_by(Model.id).fetch(10)
```

---

* Currently Oracle, PostgreSQL and MSSQL.