# Simple SELECT statement on existing table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, select, sqlalchemy

Nowhere on the internet does there exist a simple few-line tutorial on a simple `SELECT` statement for SQLAlchemy 1.0.

Assuming I've established my database connection using `create_engine()`, *and my database tables already exist*, I'd like to know how to execute the following query:

```
select
    name,
    age
from
    users
where
    name = 'joe'
    and
    age = 100
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found this while trying to figure out the same thing.

To select data from a table via SQLAlchemy, you need to build a representation of that table within SQLAlchemy. If Jupyter Notebook's response speed is any indication, that representation isn't filled in (with data from your existing database) until the query is executed.

You need `Table` to build a table. You need `select` to select data from the database. You need `metadata`... for reasons that aren't clear, even in [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table, and_

engine = create_engine("dburl://user:pass@database/schema")
metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
table = Table(
    'table_name', 
    metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine
)

stmt = select([
    table.columns.column1,
    table.columns.column2
]).where(and_(
    table.columns.column1 == 'filter1',
    table.columns.column2 == 'filter2'
))

connection = engine.connect()
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

You can then iterate over the results. See [SQLAlchemy query to return only n results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642497/sqlalchemy-query-to-return-only-n-results) on how to return one or only a few rows of data, which is useful for slower/larger queries.

```
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I checked this with a local database, and the SQLAlchemy results are not equal to the raw SQL results. The difference, for my data set, was in how the numbers were formatted. SQL returned float64 (e.g., `633.07`), while SQLAlchemy returned objects (I think `Decimal`, e.g. `633.0700000000`.)

Some help from [DataCamp's Introduction to Databases in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-relational-databases-in-python)

Comment: Pandas supports this natively via read_sql

Comment: `MetaData` is just the container for all your `Table` instances. It's essentially just a dictionary. It's required when instantiating `Table` because it keeps track of foreign key associations between tables.

Answer (score 5):

Sticking with SQL alchemy for this seems overcomplicated. What you can do instead, is to pass SQL alchemy engine component, to pandas.read_sql(sql,conn).
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine(.....)
sql = "select name, age from users where name = 'joe' and age = 100"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,con=engine)
```

Comment: note that `read_sql`, (or similar like `read_sql_table` generally have poor performance as of today

Answer (score 2):

Since the original question has two columns in the select statement, and it can confuse some people on how to write using that:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_  
stmt = select([users.columns.name,users.columns.age])  
stmt= stmt.where(and_(name=='joe',age==100)  
for res in connection.execute(stmt):  
    print(res)
```

Comment: Nice; I incorporated this into my answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While most answers points to the `and_` solution, which works perfectly (and may have been the best answer at the time) but needs imports and some counter intuitive coding, it is now possible to use a more usual way, with `&` such as, and based on @Evans answer, the code would now be (shorter import & shorter query statement):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table

engine = create_engine("dburl://user:pass@database/schema")
metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
table = Table(
    'table_name', 
    metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine
)

stmt = select([
    table.columns.column1,
    table.columns.column2
]).where(
    (table.columns.column1 == 'filter1')
    &
    (table.columns.column2 == 'filter2')
)

connection = engine.connect()
results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

Please note that, as it is specified in the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_), when using the Python `&` operator, you should use parenthesis to properly compound your query based on Python precedence rules

Answer (score -1):

I think the following will work for querying the users database table

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_
s = select([users]).where(and_(users.c.name == 'joe', users.c.age == 100))
for row in conn.execute(s):
    print row
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html

Comment: How did you declare the engine, database, connection, session, and import statements?