# Proper use of limit() and offset() in Sqlalchemy 2

Tags: sqlalchemy, pagination

This simple little exercise is to gain an understanding of how to use limit and offset in sqlalchemy queries. It runs, using sqlalchemy 2.0.22.  However, I'm reading in several places that this usage is deprecated as of version 2.0. And the documentation of what follows is highly confusing. What is the SIMPLEST new, approved syntax for getting this job done?  Same question for the slice() function.

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import URL, insert, delete, select, update

url_object = URL.create(
    "postgresql",
    username="ken",
    password="",
    host="localhost",
    database="postgres",
)
engine = db.create_engine(
    url_object
)

conn = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
numbers = db.Table('numbers', metadata,
              db.Column('id', db.Integer(),primary_key=True),
              db.Column('number', db.Integer())
              )

metadata.create_all(engine) 
for i in range(100):
    statement = insert(numbers).values(number=(i+1) * 5)
    conn.execute(statement)
conn.commit()

query = numbers.select().offset(20).limit(10)
output = conn.execute(query)
print(output.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` / `OFFSET` has not been deprecated in SQLAlchemy 2.x: there is no  deprecation notice in the documentation ([LIMIT](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.limit), [OFFSET](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.offset)).

Having said that, in v1.4 [support was introduced for the FETCH construct](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-f5dcbdf29f611c2db5b79de507e795fa)*, which is defined by the SQL standard and supported by some backends†, whereas `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` is not in the standard. [FETCH](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.fetch) also provides  additional features, such as handling ties, not provided by `LIMIT`.

It can be used in the same way as `LIMIT`:

```py
sa.select(tbl).order_by(tbl.c.id).offset(10).fetch(10)
```

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72751940/5320906) (of mine).

All things being equal, you can use either `LIMIT` or `FETCH`.

---

* The linked issue has some informative discussion [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5576#issuecomment-696084925)
† Currently Oracle, PostgreSQL and MSSQL

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw "confusing" information about this, but I'll grant that the docs for `fetch` saying "The GenerativeSelect.fetch() method will replace any clause applied with GenerativeSelect.limit()." and those for limit saying "The GenerativeSelect.limit() method will replace any clause applied with GenerativeSelect.fetch()." could certainly be clearer!