# combine into a single SQL query both the first date and the total number of dates that are returned

Tags: sql

I want to combine into a single SQL query both the first date and the total number of dates that are returned by a certain `WHERE` clause.

I can do the two separately:

```
SELECT DateAdded FROM table WHERE id = x ORDER BY DateAdded ASC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = x
```

But how do I merge these two queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about,

```
SELECT MIN(DateAdded), COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = x
```

---

Since you don't specifiy which engine you are using, this also avoids the [far from standardized `LIMIT` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528604/how-universal-is-the-limit-statement-in-sql).

Comment: For the record, I'm using MySQL. Thanks, this works like a charm.