# Is there a command in SQL like less in Linux?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I have a large table with several hundred rows that I need to view all of its row.  Is there a command in SQL that would act like the less command in Linux that would allow me to step one screen height at a time through the output of a select statement? So the pseudo-code for what I'm after would be, for example:

```
SELECT * from table less
```

Comment: The  Postgres command line client `psql` will automatically do that for you

Comment: What do you mean by "in SQL"? What program are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "paging" or "pagination"

- In MySQL and Postres it's `LIMIT n OFFSET m`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-limit.html
- In SQL Server it's `OFFSET m FETCH NEXT n`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

This QA has a more thorough answer: [How universal is the LIMIT statement in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528604/how-universal-is-the-limit-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL supports TOP N

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from table
```

Certain other dialects of SQL like SQLite support LIMIT

In DB2, you need to use SELECT * from TABLE FETCH FIRST 10 rows only