# Oracle dialect for pagination

Tags: pagination, spring-data, oracle12c, spring-data-jdbc, dialect

We are retrieving data from oracle using spring data JDBC

We are using `org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.OracleDialect` to retrieve data from database.

It is working as expected when we have a repository that uses `CrudRepository`

But if we modify the repository which extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` to retrieve based on the page number, we are getting an exception.

Based on the analysis, we identified that queries generated by `LIMIT_CLAUSE` and `LOCK_CLAUSE` do not adhere to Oracle.

Is there an Oracle dialect to generate a proper limit query which is an instance of `org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect`?

Comment: which version of hibernate and Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle version is 12c...Not using hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only available `OracleDialect is based on the` AnsiDialect` and Oracle12c is supposed to support the ANSI standard.

Further investigation leads to the suspicion that the ANSI standard allows multiple variants and `AnsiDialect` creates a clause that does not work with Oracle12 although it gets accepted by OracleXE18 which is used for testing.

Spring Data JDBC currently creates clauses of the form `OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH FIRST %d ROWS ONLY`. Which according to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/ansi-iso-plans-for-limit-standardization is conforming to the standard.

But https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046664/66686 hints that Oracle12 might require `OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY`

As a workaround you may register a custom dialect as described in https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0#dialects

Comment: Thanks for your information. May I know how to do the same in Oracle 11g?

Comment: The syntax for Oracle11 requires an inner select. This is currently not supported by Spring Data JDBC

Comment: I am thinking of the following option for 11g. Can you suggest the better one? 1. Create a stored procedure with inner select. 2. Use ROWNUM in the query. 3. Is it possible to use RowMapper? If so, consider this also an alternative.

Comment: I'd prefer to use the proper SQL in a `@Query` annotation and pass `limit` and `offset` as parameters. Possibly adding a default method calling the first one and taking a `Pageable` as argument.