# Win32_Process query optimization

Tags: c#, sql, linq, win32-process

I am working on a query on Win32_Process to get some info about running processes

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " + processId);

ManagementObject process = mSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (process != null)
        {
            string[] argList = {string.Empty, string.Empty};
            int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
            Username = returnVal == 0 ? argList[0] : "";
            try
            {
                Description = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo((string) process["ExecutablePath"]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Description = "";
            }
        }
```

This query takes long time, so I am trying to make 3 solutions combination

> 1- ("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " +
>   processId);

But: Not accepted (Invalid query)

> 2- Using Linq to sql to get the first or default value directly with
>   linq

But: couldn't make it

> 3-("SELECT TOP 1 ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " +  processId);

but assuming that TOP 1 worked, I cannot:

```
int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
```

So what is the best solution for this function to be as fast as possible

Comment: [WQL does not support TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574336/wql-does-not-support-top-need-workaround)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Windows API directly.  You could try to use function called `NTQuerySystemInformation` from NTDLL.dll or higher level kernel32 function using ToolHelp32

Google how to P/Invoke those functions and use them. C# gives you very strong interface for interaction with WinAPI features and you must use it for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict retriving data with "Handle" and "ExecutablePath".

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Handle, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " + processId);
```

With process handle you could call `GetOwner` method.

Comment: Thanks that solved part of my problem, but the function still slow