# Oracle SQL - How to Retrieve highest 5 values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

How do you write a query where only a select number of rows are returned with either the highest or lowest column value.

i.e.  A report with the 5 highest salaried employees?

Answer (score 26):

The best way to do this is with analytic functions, RANK() or DENSE_RANK() ...

```
SQL> select * from (
  2        select empno
  3               , sal
  4               , rank() over (order by sal desc) as rnk
  5        from emp)
  6  where rnk <= 5
  7  /

     EMPNO        SAL        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839       5000          1
      7788       3000          2
      7902       3000          2
      7566       2975          4
      8083       2850          5
      7698       2850          5

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

DENSE_RANK() compresses the gaps when there is a tie:

```
SQL> select * from (
  2        select empno
  3               , sal
  4               , dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as rnk
  5        from emp)
  6  where rnk <= 5
  7  /

     EMPNO        SAL        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839       5000          1
      7788       3000          2
      7902       3000          2
      7566       2975          3
      8083       2850          4
      7698       2850          4
      8070       2500          5

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Which behaviour you prefer depends upon your business requirements.

There is also the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function which we can use to return a precise number of rows.  However, we should avoid using solutions based on row number unless the business logic is happy to arbitrarily truncate the result set in the event of a tie.   There is a difference between asking for *the five highest values* and the *first five records sorted by high values*

There is also a non-analytic solution using the ROWNUM pseudo-column.  This is clunky because ROWNUM is applied before the ORDER BY clause, which can lead to unexpected results.  There is rarely any reason to use ROWNUM instead of ROW_NUMBER() or one of the ranking functions.

Comment: You can use `QUALIFY ... <= 5` instead of wrapping it in another select.

Comment: @lins314159 - QUALIFY is not a construct which Oracle supports.

Comment: I thought it did. Or is the link talking about some other Oracle product?`http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12032_01/doc/epm.921/html_ir_studio/ir_studio-15-36.html`

Comment: That's the "Hyperion System 9 BI+ Interactive Reporting Interactive Reporting Studio" which looks like it supports more than Oracle standard SQL.

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT field1, field2 FROM fields order by field1 desc) 
where rownum <= 5
```

Also take a look on [this resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106025708/https://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html) for a more detailed description on how rownum works.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 9i+ provides analytic functions:

- [ROW_NUMBER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)
- [RANK](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php)
- [DENSE_RANK](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dense_rank.php)

All require the use of the `OVER` clause, which allows `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to properly tune the `ROW_NUMBER`/`RANK`/`DENSE_RANK` value returned.

Prior to 9i, the only option was to work with `ROWNUM` - which incidentally is faster than using `ROW_NUMBER` ([link](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)).

Comment: Actually Oracle introduced the Analytic functions in 8i, but only as under the Enterprise Edition license.  In 9i they came under the Standard Edition license.

Answer (score 3):

In **Oracle 12c**, this can be achieved using `FETCH..FIRST`  `ROWS..ONLY`

To fetch the top 5 highest salaries.

```
 SELECT *
       FROM EMPLOYEES
   ORDER BY SALARY DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select emp_id , salary from employees
  Order by salary desc
  Limit 5;
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not oracle syntax. It is used in some other database though, such as mysql/mariadb/postgresql/sqlite syntax, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/595155/44862