# query to find the second most common word in a table (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

So I have a table employees as shown below

```
ID | name | department
---|------|-----------
1  | john | home
2  | alex | home
3  | ryan | tech
```

I'm trying to group these by the department number and have the count displayed.  But I am trying to select the second most common, which in this case it should return (tech 1).  Any help on how to approach this is appreciated.

**Edit:**

By only using `MINUS`, I'm still not familiar with `LIMIT` when searching around online.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491063/how-to-find-the-employee-with-the-second-highest-salary (using the `COUNT` in the order by clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `COUNT` along with `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT department, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY department
)

SELECT department, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 2;
```

As of Oracle 12c, you might find the following limit query satisfactory:

```sql
SELECT department, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

But this limit approach does not handle well the scenario where e.g. there might be 2 or more departments ties for first place.  `DENSE_RANK` does a better job of handling such edge cases.

Comment: is there another way without the use of DENSE_RANK

Comment: If there are multiple top ranked rows then `OFFSET 1 FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` will fetch one of the joint-top values and not the second ranked value. If there is only one top-ranked row then the equivalent to `DENSE_RANK` would be `OFFSET 1 FETCH NEXT 1 ROW WITH TIES` (but that still would get the wrong value if there are multiple top-ranked values).