# how to get latest 'n' updated row from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, top-n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle SQL - How to Retrieve highest 5 values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306744/oracle-sql-how-to-retrieve-highest-5-values-of-a-column)

i have a table abc, where i have following columns

`act_id,cust_id,lastUpdatedDate,custActivity`. Where **act_id is primary key** .

lastUpdatedDate store last activity done for this customer.

i am trying to get latest 10 rows for given custid based on lastUpdatedDate.

How can i achieve it.

-vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ROWNUM** in Oracle.. Click [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm) for Documentation

```
select *
from  
   ( select * 
     from your_table 
     where cust_id=<given cust_id>
     order by lastUpdatedDate desc ) 
where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports **[`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)** and window function. Try the following,

```
SELECT act_id, cust_id, lastUpdatedDate, custActivity
FROM
(
    SELECT  act_id, cust_id, lastUpdatedDate, custActivity,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY lastUpdatedDate DESC) rn
    FROM tableNAME
) x
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helpful to you-

```
select act_id,cust_id,lastUpdatedDate,custActivity
  from (
    select act_id,cust_id,lastUpdatedDate,custActivity, row_number() over (order by lastUpdatedDate) r
      from abc
    where act_id=<cust_id>
  )
where r between 1 and 10;
```