# Finding the MAX

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle SQL - How to Retrieve highest 5 values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306744/oracle-sql-how-to-retrieve-highest-5-values-of-a-column)

I have a simple question for someone who knows anything about SQL but since i'm very new and although I have tried many different ways, I can never seem to get the syntax correct. I want to display only the average hotel which is the MAX result. Currently it displays the average of all the hotels individually. Is this something I can use the MAX function for? I am using oracle

```
SELECT HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", ROUND(AVG (R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE"
FROM ROOM JOIN HOTEL ON HOTEL.HOTEL_NO = ROOM.HOTEL_NO
WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Shangra_La'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Hilton'
OR HOTEL.H_NAME = 'Sheraton'
GROUP BY HOTEL.H_NAME
ORDER BY HOTEL.H_NAME;
```

Comment: The MAX function will give you the highest value, that is the highest price.  I don't understand what you mean by "the average hotel which is the MAX result".

Comment: Please could you elaborate on what `I want to display only the average hotel which is the MAX result.` means?  If possible, include example input data and an example fo the output you desire/expect.

Comment: Sorry guys I worded it poorly. Currently the query displays the average room price of 3 separate hotels. I want the query to return the Hotel which has the highest average price per hotel room out of the 3.

Comment: @danboy - The terms highest and average are usually mutually exclusive. Say three hotels `A, B, C` have prices of `150.00, 169.00, 180.00`. The *average* price is ~`166.33`. None of them have the "average" price. However hotel `C` has the highest price: `180.00`. So what do you mean by "highest average price". As mentioned, a data sample would really help clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can use the `ROWNUM` pseudo column.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        HOTEL.H_NAME "HOTEL NAME", 
        ROUND(AVG (R_PRICE), 1) "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE" 
    FROM
        ROOM 
            JOIN HOTEL ON HOTEL.HOTEL_NO = ROOM.HOTEL_NO 
    WHERE HOTEL.H_NAME IN ('Shangra_La','Hilton','Sheraton')
    GROUP BY HOTEL.H_NAME 
) v
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY "AVERAGE ROOM PRICE" DESC;
```

Comment: `Order by` clause should be applied to the sub-query if you want to get maximum value of price. Otherwise you are just ordering 1 row - first.