# how to get first female of each tool, oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle SQL - How to Retrieve highest 5 values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306744/oracle-sql-how-to-retrieve-highest-5-values-of-a-column)

I'm writing oracle query but stuck in the following problem

table is like this:

```
**Tool**       **Name**       **Gender**
Facebook   Alice        F
Facebook   Alex         M
Facebook   Loong        M
Facebook   Jimmy        M
Twitter    James        M
Twitter    Jessica      F
Twitter    Sam          M
Twitter    Kathrine     F
Google     Rosa         F
Google     Lily         F
Google     Bob          M
```

What I wanna get is the first female in each tool
the result should be like:

```
Facebook   Alice
Twitter    Jessica
Google     Rosa
```

I'm trying to get this by using query not functions or procedures
Thank for helping

Comment: How do you know Kathrine isn't the first female for Twitter?

Comment: Your definition of "first" is ambiguous.  'Lily' clearly comes before 'Rosa' in an alphabetical sort, so to make 'Rosa' come ahead of 'Lily' requires a different ordering criterion.  You haven't provided any additional columns, so it is impossible to achieve your proposed result set in a deterministic fashion.  Please edit your question to clarify your requirement: either include the additional sort column(s) or state that you just want a random row as the "first" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by tool order by name) as rn
        ,       Name
        ,       Tool
        from    YourTable
        where   Gender = 'F'
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only first per tool
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e72ae/12/0)

Comment: Hello, please read my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is another alternative.

```
select min(name), tool
from yourTable
where gender = 'F'
group by tool
```

I'd like to have a little bit of a discussion on which is better or which does what, for me its the first time I see `row_number()`. Note thas this one returns the female in the alphabetical order, yours does the same by sorting in a window, what is the difference?

Comment: +1 good answer-- this works as long as you don't have to select other columns besides Name.  For example, if you have to return first and last name, `min` might pick the first name of one person, and the last name of another.