# How to limit this using rownum in oracle

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle SQL - How to Retrieve highest 5 values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306744/oracle-sql-how-to-retrieve-highest-5-values-of-a-column)

Hey so I have a query to do this:
Write a query which retrieves only the ten companies with the highest number of pickups over the six-month period
The 6 months I have been given and I tried many queries this is what I have but I know its wrong as I have no idea

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT customers.name,COUNT(MANIFEST.MANIFEST_BARCODE) AS Pickups
FROM customers JOIN manifest ON (Reference = pickup_reference) 
ORDER BY Pickups desc;)
WHERE ROWNUM < 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your table structures etc. I've no idea where the six-month restriction fits in, but for the rest you have an aggregate function (`count`) without a `group by` clause, and a random semi-colon in your inner query. Something like this ought to work and is close to what you already have:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT customers.name, COUNT(manifest.manifest_barcode) AS Pickups
    FROM customers
    JOIN manifest ON (Reference = pickup_reference)
    GROUP BY customers.name
    ORDER BY pickups DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM < 11;
```

There are a lot of examples on this site, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2498035/266304) for example.

Comment: Yeah I was on a time limit, bad time management so was rushing, however that works great thanks.