# How to select top N from a table

Tags: sql

I have to select the top 25 records from a table according to the column `Num`.

There are two issues. First, the table is not sorted by `Num`. I know this can be resolved by using `GROUP ORDER BY`. Second, the number of the records in the table might be less than 25.

Is there any way to perform this selection in just one SQL statement?

Comment: How you do this particular task is largely dependent on your specific RDBMS, as you can already see by some of the differing solutions below. You should always try to specify that in your question if it's appropriate (i.e., not a "general" or ANSI standard SQL question)

Comment: I have to nitpick this because it's an important concept... in SQL tables do not have an order. The particular server may store them in a specific order on disk (or they may not), but if you want ordering in your results you should ALWAYS use the ORDER BY clause (which is different from the GROUP BY clause). As far as I know, there is no GROUP ORDER BY clause in any RDBMS that I've used.

Comment: the accepted answer to [...this question...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword) lists ways to do this for DB2, Informix, SQL Server, Access, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**For SQL Server:**

```
select top 25 * from table order by Num asc
```

**For mySQL:**

```
select * from table order by Num asc limit 25
```

Comment: Like this because you give alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle:

```
Select *
FROM Table
WHERE rownum <= 25
```

MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 25 * 
from Table
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: These don't include the Num column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 25 *
from your_table
order by Num asc
```

On SQL Server that would select the 25 first records starting from the lowest value of Num. If you need the highest, use "desc" instead of "asc".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database implementation you're using, it could be using the limit statement (as one other answer suggests) or it could be like this:

```
SELECT TOP 25 Num, blah, blah ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on your database, as there is no standard way to do this.

In SQL Server, for example, I have used Row_Number (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do this, so I can select which group I was interested in (for paging, for example), but `Top` also works.

For Oracle you can look at rownum (http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/examples/first_rows.html).

And MySQL has been mentioned already.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
  LIMIT 25
```

Comment: LIMIT is a construct in MySQL.

Comment: The OP didn't specify his RDBMS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the requirement, but you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 25 Num FROM Blah WHERE Num = 'MyCondition'
```

If there aren't 25 records, you won't get 25.  You can perform an `ORDER BY` and the `TOP` will listen to that.

Answer (score 0):

`Select Top 25 [Column] From [Table] Order By [Column]`

If you have fewer than 25 records, this will just pull however many there are.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebird,

```
select first 25 
from your_table
order by whatever
```