# query for selecting top 5 salaries from table

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select top N from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353446/how-to-select-top-n-from-a-table)

How can a write a query for selecting the top 5 salaries from table ?

Comment: Ok, I'll take 2!  This isn't a real question, and you haven't given any context (e.g. table schema).  Voted to close.

Comment: Please read the FAQ and try to ask a question that can be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Give him a chance to clarify before you close his question, there's obviously a real question here. @shailesh please specify what database you're using and provide some context to your question (table structure)

Comment: What would your answer have to be if there were 10 people with the same salary and that is the second highest?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Salary
   FROM SalariesTable
   ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Salary
FROM Salaries
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the `TOP 5` highest Salaries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 MAX(Salary)
  FROM Salaries
 GROUP
    BY Salary
 ORDER 
    BY Salary DESC;
```