# Emulate group by, order by, limit from mysql to ms sql 2000

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a query in MySQL:

```
select slscod,slsname,brc
from td_casa
group by slscod
order by slsname
limit 0,100
```

This query retrieves the top 100 unique sales codes with `slsname` and `brc`, ordered by `slsname` ascending.

How to change this query in MSSQL 2000?

Comment: Have you tried running it on SQL Server? Does it return any error messages?

Comment: @a'r: this isn't valid SQL Server syntax which is quite obvious. Which is why the question has been asked...

Answer (score 3):

The basic syntax is:

```
select top 100 slscod,slsname,brc 
from td_casa 
group by slscod 
order by slsname
```

Comment: does not work, I get an error : [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Column 'td_casa.slsname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 100 slscod, slsname, brc
FROM td_casa
GROUP BY slscod, slsname, brc
ORDER BY slsname
```

Note: regarding your comment about *Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select ...* error I noticed that you were selecting 3 columns but specified 1 column in the `GROUP BY` clause. This is a MySQL specific behavior as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY to permit selecting fields that are
>   not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause. If you are not getting the
>   results that you expect from your query, please read the description
>   of GROUP BY found in Section 11.15, "Functions and Modifiers for Use
>   with GROUP BY Clauses".

Comment: I had a problem again if taking the limit, for example in mysql I want to take the start record 30 until 100. This was in mysql query : select slscod,slsname,brc from td_casa group by slscod order by slsname limit 30,100. How to change this query in MSSQL 2000?

Comment: @IrfaniFirdausy: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server

Comment: I am afraid with MSSQL2000 your hands are tied. But this is worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword

Comment: Oh, yes, SQL-Server-2000 has limited options for the OFFSET version. See also this article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml

Comment: And the answer by @leoinfo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server

Comment: And a rather old article with some performance analysis on various methods (not all applicable to SQL-Server 2000): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx

Comment: Instead of using `MIN`, just extend the `GROUP BY` clause to include all "selected" columns. Both methods will return same results (assuming that sslcod is a primary/unique key).

Comment: finally, i found this query.
I'll answer it tomorrow. because Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

because in MSSQL 2000 does not support the  `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LIMIT ... OFFSET ..`
finally, i found this query :

```
SELECT slscod, MIN(slsname) slsname, MIN(brc) brc FROM (
    SELECT top 30 slscod, MIN(slsname) slsname, MIN(brc) brc FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP (1*30) slscod, MIN(slsname) slsname, MIN(brc) brc
        FROM td_casa group by slscod
        ORDER BY slsname ASC
    ) AS t1 group by slscod
     ORDER BY slsname DESC ) AS t2 group by slscod ORDER BY MIN(slsname) ASC
```

This is the same if in mysql :

```
select slscod,slsname,brc from td_casa group by slscod order by slsname limit 0,30
```

if you change `TOP (2*30)` this is the same `limit 30,30`.  `TOP (3*30)` this is the same `limit 60,30` and so on.

desperate need of effort.
thanks all.let's cheers