# sql get max based on field

Tags: sql

I need to get the ID based from what ever the max amount is. Below is giving me an error

```
   select  ID from Prog 
   where Amount = MAX(Amount)
```

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

The end result is that I need to get the just the ID as I need to pass it something else that is expecting it.

Comment: is this sql-server? mysql? or something else?

Comment: All these answers assumed you only wanted one row -- what did you expect to do if there was more than one id with the maximum amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to order by Amount and select 1 record instead...

```
SELECT ID
FROM Prog
ORDER BY Amount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This takes all the rows in `Prog`, orders them in descending order by `Amount` (in other words, the first sorted row has the highest `Amount`), then limits the query to select only one row (the one with the highest `Amount`).

Also, subqueries are bad for performance. This code runs on a table with 200k records in half the time as the subquery versions.

Comment: Your solution is the same solution that got one upvote, just in standard SQL and you got a downvote, i don't really understand why ... I think that someone here press down vote without any reason ... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server that should do it :

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID 
FROM Prog
ORDER BY Amount DESC
```

Comment: FYI - this will work on SQL server, but not MySQL. OP didn't specify DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a subquery with the max value to the where clause :

```
   select  ID from Prog 
   where Amount = (SELECT MAX(Amount) from Prog)
```

Comment: Sometimes i really can't understand why some correct answers get downvoted ... Could someone explain whats wrong with my solution ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know, I think some a** was coming through downvoting every answer... back up to 0 now though! :D

Comment: Maybe today is the downvote day, and we didn't noticed that ... :-)

Comment: It's backwards day! Downvotes are upvotes and upvotes are downvotes!

Comment: Oh and this will also select more than one row if they have the same `Amount` value.

Answer (score 1):

This should be something like:

```
select P.ID from Prog P
where P.Amount = (select max(Amount) from Prog)
```

---

EDIT:

If you really want only 1 row, you should do:

```
select max(P.ID) from Prog P
where P.Amount = (select max(Amount) from Prog);
```

However, if you have multiple rows that would match amount and you only want 1 row, you should have some kind of logic behind how you pick your one row.  Not just relying on this max trick, or `limit 1` type logic.

Also, I don't write `limit 1`, because this is not ANSI sql -- it works in mysql but OP doesn't say what he wants.  Every db is different -- see here:  [Is there an ANSI SQL alternative to the MYSQL LIMIT keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595123/341547)    Don't get used to one db's extensions unless you only want to work in 1 db for the rest of your life.

Comment: This will select more than one row if they have the same `Amount` value.

Comment: True -- typed fast.  Everyone's using `limit 1` or `max` or something like that.  But unless he wants essentially random results, questioner should be using some kind of business logic to pick the 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

```
select min(ID) from Prog 
where Amount in 
(
    select max(amount)
    from prog
)
```

The min statement ensures that you get only one result.

Comment: Using `LIMIT 1` also ensures you only get one result, and doesn't require any explanation.