# MS Access give an error when trying to use a query using SELECT TOP 0 *

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, export-to-excel

i would like a clear answer of why can't i process a query like this one with OleDb

```
"select top 0 * FROM [APPELLATION$] WHERE (((([libel_app] LIKE '%g') OR ([region] LIKE '%g')) OR ([couleur] LIKE '%g')))"
```

I can with SQL but when i try to fetch some data from an Excel file it throws an error that tells me that i use some restricted word or i have some symbols that are restricted. I read the list of restricted words and symbols and did not find any of them in my query. My program is giving me SQL request, i would not like to end up looking if the TOP N number is whether or not is zero, but if i have no solution...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What result do you expect from 'select top 0'?  This doesn't really make sense...

Comment: It doesn't make sense for my use, but i end up with it because of some methods implemented by my collegues, since it works for SQL and i am the only one using oleDb they don't changed it.

Comment: If you remove the "top 0" does it work without error?

Comment: Yes, and it works with any other number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collegues should remove hard-coded flavor-specific SQL from their code in the first place especially if it is to be used on different types of connections.

See the accepted answer on [Is there an ANSI SQL alternative to the MYSQL LIMIT keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword) for some of the flavors. Excel is not listed there, I bet it uses the same syntax as MsAccess but I'm not suprised it acts completely different upon such a weird query. As Paddy already mentioned that query does not make any sense, and should be avoided.

Fixing this by matching "SELECT TOP 0" is ugly and will make maintaining software pure hell (been there :( )

Comment: "I bet it uses the same syntax as MsAccess" -- Indeed it uses the Access database engine, hence the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `N` in `TOP N` must be a numeric value of 1 (Banker's rounded) or greater.

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 0.5 * FROM MyTable;  -- rounds to zero = error

SELECT TOP 0.6 * FROM MyTable;  -- rounds to 1 = no problem
```