# Select 1000 distinct names from 100 million records via standard sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, standards, ansi-sql

I have a table `tb_FirstName` with one field `FirstName`. The table has 100 million non null records with lots of repetitions e.g. John occurs 2 million times. The distinct count of `FirstName` is over 2 million.

How do I select 1000 *distinct* names as quickly as possible using **standard** sql?

I'm currently using the following but this is

- tSQL
- Maybe not as efficient as it could be.

  ```
  SELECT x.FirstName
  FROM (
      SELECT  FirstName,
              rnk = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Firstname)
      FROM    WHData.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount A
      GROUP BY FirstName
      ) x
  WHERE rnk <=1000
  ```

Comment: You might find this usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword  but may I ask what's the intention for having a table tb_FirstName full of duplicates?

Comment: @bummi this question is a slimmed down example of the reality - the table actually has 30 fields but no need to include that in the question

Comment: 100MM names? sounds like a spam/marketing database of personal info... not sure if to help you or not

Comment: @RemusRusanu we have lots of users over past 10+yrs. Not spam and not marketing. Just analysis.

Comment: For analysis you should extract all the distinct names into a separate table, once, and then join at will with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like you could use `TOP 1000` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISINCT TOP 1000 FirstName
FROM WHData.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount
ORDER BY FirstName
```

[Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0437/1)

Comment: @whytheq -- np, glad we could help!

Comment: FYI: does not work on columns that can't be compared, like XML or TEXT.

Comment: Works perfectly! Although you have a typo - DISTINCT is spelled wrong ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FirstName FROM 
(SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName ORDER BY FirstName) NO,
 FirstName FROM WHData.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount )
  AS T1 WHERE no =1
```

or

```
SELECT DISINCT TOP 1000 FirstName
FROM WHData.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount ORDER BY FirstName
```

Comment: The second approach is very appealing. It is neat and accurate. Plus it is very readable.

Comment: OP asks for standard SQL, while `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION...` looks like tSQL feature.

Comment: Second is ANSI standard me believes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have an index defined on FirstName.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FirstName
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FirstName
FROM dbo.tb_DimUserAccount) N
ORDER BY FirstName
```

Comment: No performance improvement because full table scan is being done in sub query. This is same as post.

Comment: True, full table scan still required but performance slightly better performance than post

Answer (score 2):

You need the data after sorting the results on FirstName fields.

It requires full table scan if Index is not created. If Index is created on FirstName then Unique Index scan can improve the time.

Comment: 2+ John's is not a rare scenario

Comment: We can't place the clustered Index, so Unique Index will have better performance rather than a normal non clustered index.

Comment: Unique index is ok only if the target column contains only unique elements. According to the name of the column `FirstName` it is highly unlikely this to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Option with GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FirstName
FROM WHData.dbo.tb_DimUserAccount
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY FirstName
```