# What is the SQL standard way to limit the number of return values?

Tags: sql

I tried to find the standard way to limit the number of return values of a select query, but I can not find it in the [BNF](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#table%20expression). Every DBMS seems to define [its own way](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp). Is there a standard way? And if not, why is not worth to standardize it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword) here...

Comment: Many products implemented their own versions before the SQL standard specified the FETCH FIRST syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It **is** standardized.

The SQL standard defines the following syntax:

```
select * 
from some_table
order by id
fetch first 42 rows only;
```

Alternatively to start at a different row than the first one:

```
select * 
from some_table
order by id
offset 42
fetch first 42 rows only;
```

This was introduced in SQL:2008

However not every DBMS supports the standard for this. Actually no DBMS **fully** supports everything that is defined in the standard. Some ignore the standard more than others.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Limiting_result_rows) the following DBMS supporting this:

- PostgreSQL (8.4)
- Oracle 12c
- IBM DB2
- SQL Server 2012
- HSQLDB 2.0
- H2
- CA DATACOM/DB 11
- Sybase SQL Anywhere
- EffiProz

Comment: Mimer SQL supports it too.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 supports OFFSET/FETCH as well. You can read about both standard and vendor-specific ways of limiting rows here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Limiting_result_rows

Comment: I still can not find it in the BNF as a part of the `SELECT` statement. The `FETCH` occurs in the grammar as a part of the [data statement](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#SQL%20data%20statement) which is part of a procedure, a trigger or a cursor, but not part of a basic `SELECT`.

Comment: @ceving: that is SQL:2003, the `fetch first...` was added in SQL:2008

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is the 2008 grammar anywhere in the web?

Comment: I should have read the Wikipedia article. It explains it quite well.