# T-SQL Skip Take Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I don't seem to be having much luck on this site, still forever the optimist, I will keep trying.
I have two tables, Journals and ArticleCategories that are joined using the this query:

```
SELECT Journals.JournalId,
       Journals.Year,
       Journals.Title,
       ArticleCategories.ItemText
FROM   Journals
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ArticleCategories
         ON Journals.ArticleCategoryId = ArticleCategories.ArticleCategoryId
```

Can anyone tell me how I can re-write this make it into a Skip, Take query.
In other words, I want to it skip the first n records and then take the next n.
I think ROW_NUMBER is involved somewhere but I cannot work out how to use it in this case.

I suspect the reason why don't have much luck is that I find it difficult to explain what I am trying to do.
If my question is not clear, please do not hesitate to tell me where I am going wrong and I will gladly try again.
Perhaps I should also mention that I am trying to put this in a stored procedure.
Many Thanks.
Many thanks,

Comment: `first n records ` - as ordered by what?

Comment: Good point! I forgot to mention it needs to be ordered by something. Could I impose on you once again and ask how to include  ORDER BY Journals.Year? Many thanks Martin.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment Martin. If I had been more careful, I would have noticed you had included an ORDER BY statement. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For 2005 / 2008 / 2008 R2

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  Journals.JournalId, 
            Journals.Year, 
            Journals.Title, 
            ArticleCategories.ItemText,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (ORDER BY Journals.JournalId,ArticleCategories.ItemText) AS RN
    FROM    Journals LEFT OUTER JOIN
            ArticleCategories 
             ON Journals.ArticleCategoryId = ArticleCategories.ArticleCategoryId
)
    SELECT  JournalId, 
            Year, 
            Title, 
            ItemText
FROM cte
WHERE RN BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

For 2012 this is simpler

```
SELECT Journals.JournalId,
       Journals.Year,
       Journals.Title,
       ArticleCategories.ItemText
FROM   Journals
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ArticleCategories
         ON Journals.ArticleCategoryId = ArticleCategories.ArticleCategoryId
ORDER  BY Journals.JournalId,
          ArticleCategories.ItemText 
OFFSET  10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks Martin, that worked perfectly. Very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Martin Smith's correct answer - when using a `GROUP BY`, you can't use `OFFSET-FETCH` without an `ORDER BY`:

```
GROUP BY [cols]

ORDER BY [col] ASC|DESC

OFFSET  10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The following gives "incorrect syntaxt near 'OFFSET'" :

```
GROUP BY [cols]

--ORDER BY [col] ASC|DESC

OFFSET  10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```