# Pagination sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why is this query not working in Sql Server 2008?

```
Select Top @PageSize Skip @Page * @PageSize * From someTable
```

Strangely even this doesn't work :-

```
Select Top @PageSize * From Tree
```

But this one works :-

```
Select Top 10 * From Tree
```

This statement is inside Stored procedure.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is not valid syntax at all.

The second one just needs brackets (and should have an `ORDER BY`)

```
Select Top (@PageSize) * 
From Tree
ORDER BY /*TODO: Add column(s)*/
```

To achieve what you are apparently trying to do in the first case you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `BETWEEN` as in this answer [T-SQL Skip Take Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620758/t-sql-skip-take-stored-procedure/5620802#5620802)

Answer (score 2):

you need parentheses

```
Select Top ( @PageSize ) * From Tree
```

However without an order by it doesn't make a lot of sense

SKIP is not valid SQL Server syntax, the first query won't work