# Invalid column name SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What do I have to do to use name `Rowss` in the `WHERE` clause ?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dp.IdPytanie) AS Rowss,
    dp.IdPytanie
    ,dp.SpecjalnePytanie
 FROM dodajtemat_pytanie dp
 WHERE 
    (@RowBegining = 0 OR convert(int,Rowss) >= @RowBegining)
    AND (@RowEnd = 0 OR Rowss <= @RowEnd)
```

Error
[image]

This work  ->

```
 @RowEnd = 0 OR ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dp.IdPytanie) <= @RowEnd
```

Comment: You cannot reference in a WHERE clause an alias given to a column of the same query, you need to go with a subquery, or replace Rowss with its full expression.

Comment: As you are on 2012 you might want to look at [`OFFSET ... FETCH`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5620802/73226)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a subquery or a *CTE* like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dp.IdPytanie) AS Rowss,
      dp.IdPytanie,
      dp.SpecjalnePytanie
    FROM dodajtemat_pytanie dp
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE (@RowBegining = 0 OR Rowss >= @RowBegining)
  AND (@RowEnd      = 0 OR Rowss <= @RowEnd);
```

The `WHERE` clause is *logically* evaluated before the `SELECT` statement, so that it doesn't recognize that newly created alias `Rowss`.

Fore more information about the logical query processing steps in SQL Server, see:

- [**Logical Query Processing Poster by  Itzik Ben**](http://www.sql.co.il/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Comment: but I will lost a lot in optimization

Comment: because I take all arguments and later I take only this which I want. Take all arguments is mistake because procedure will be slower. Of course your answer is correct and I will accept this. Tahnks for help and your time.

Comment: And why are you doing the conversion? `convert(int, Rowss)`

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal  ok I will test this.

Comment: @ypercube this was only example, I know Rowss is int :)

Comment: @ypercube - Sorry, I just copied it from the question. Fixed now.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper why do you think a CTE will optimize differently than the query you originally wrote (if that were legal syntax)?