# SQL statement with pagination and sorting (join tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I have two tables (**Books, Authors**) with ***ManyToMany*** relationship. **I need SQL statement** to retrieve *books with authors*, *sorted by authors/books*. Important thing is that I must retrieve them *with pagination* (offset ... fetch in sql).
One of the problem that when I join tables there are duplicates in results (of course) and offset/fetch can't be used for this results. Another problem the results must be sorted (not subpages but all books of course).

I have one idea: (it retrieves books sorted by author name and include pagination)

```
select  b.id, b.title, a.name from Books b inner join Books_Authors ba
                          on ba.bookID = b.id inner join Authors a
                          on ba.authorID = a.id     
                          where a.name in (select name from Authors order by name offset 9 rows fetch next 3  rows only)
                          order by a.name
```

But I think it's not efficient way.

Comment: Depending which version of MSSS you're using with dictate the method. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5620802/100283

Comment: @ Mark Kram, my problem that I must retrieve, for example, 3 books (if pagesize = 3) with its authors (from table Authors). So I should JOIN two tables, but the result will contain dublicates of books (because book can have several authors), so if I use for this result pagination (ex. OFFSET...FETCH) I won't get 3 books (I'll get 1 book in case this book has 3 authors).

Comment: Then you may need to use a Cross Apply to retrieve the rows you want from the Books table.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The question is about a reasonable optimization: have the database limit the size of the result, instead of spewing out 10,000 rows and the user code throw away 9,900.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
   select * from 
            (
                 select tmp1.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.title, a.name order by b.id, a.id) rang2 
                 from 
                 (
                 select a.id,  b.id, b.title, a.name, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.title, a.name order by b.id, a.id) rang 
                 from Books b inner join Books_Authors ba on ba.bookID = b.id 
                 inner join Authors a on ba.authorID = a.id
                 ) tmp1 where rang=1 
            ) tmp2 
   where rang2 between 3 and 9
   order by title, name
```

Comment: The ordering (title, name) must be imposed on the complete result set, then you keep page 1 (e.g., rows 1..20) or etc. from that set, so there are no repeats across pages.  It appears - I'm not entirely certain - that this answer only sorts the rows 3..9 by title, name.

Answer (score -3):

table1

```
sno   exam      questions   time_duration
1   unit test    1              10
2   mock 1       2              10
3   mock2        5              10
4   mock3        6               6
```

table2

```
qid answer user_attempt_option
1      1           1
2      2           3
2      3           4
3      4           1
3      1           2
3      2           3
3      3           1
```

Comment: can you provide an explanation on how did you come up with this anwer?

Comment: pagination query how to combine two tables using php