# Dapper ORM paging and sorting

Tags: vb.net, orm, dapper

I am giving the Dapper ORM a try. I am able to query data from a table using the code below:

```
Dim comments As List(Of Comment)
Using conn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    comments = conn.Query(Of Comment)("SELECT * from comments where userid = @commentid", New With {.userid= 1})
End Using

Return View(comments)
```

I am interested to learn how to do paging/sorting using Dapper. EF has "skip" and "take" to help with this. I understand that a micro ORM does not have this built in but would like to know the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to do skip and take with Dapper, [you do it with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758186/how-to-get-n-rows-starting-from-row-m-from-sorted-table-in-t-sql).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT tbl.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rownum
FROM comments as tbl
) seq
 WHERE seq.rownum BETWEEN @x AND @y
 AND userid = @commentid
 ORDER BY seq.rownum
```

Comment: yes, also keep in mind this is db dependent, oracle and mysql have limit and offset, denali has offset and so on.

Comment: The **where** should be inside the inner query, no? And you should probably have an explicit **order by rownum** on the final query (cc @Sam)

Comment: @Marc yes you would need an order by at then end .. the where may or may not be needed in the inner query, sometimes you can add a TOP @y to the inner query to get a perf boost

Comment: Wouldn't you do TOP (@pagesize) rather than TOP (@y)? "@y" will be an absolute rownumber not the number of records you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it now. 
All you'd need to do is write an extension method that takes Query and PageSize and PageNumber, then you need to append the

```
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

line to the query and execute. 
**Note that the query absolutely requires an ORDER-BY clause**  (at least in T-SQL).
This would work for MS-SQL (2012+), PostgreSQL (8.4+), and Oracle (12c+).
For MySQL, you'd have to append LIMIT offset, page_size.

```
LIMIT @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1), @PageSize
```

For Firebird, you'd have to append ROWS x TO y

```
ROWS (@PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1)) TO (@PageSize * @PageNumber -1)
```

For a base-1 index, it would be from startoffset_base1 to endoffset_base1

```
StartAt @PageSize * (pagenum - 1) + 1 EndAt @PageSize * (pagenum - 1) + @PageSize
```

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @PageSize int 
DECLARE @PageNumber int 
SET @PageSize = 5
SET @PageNumber = 2

SELECT * FROM T_Users
ORDER BY USR_ID 
-- Must contain "ORDER BY" 
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

For the syntax on various different RDBMS, see
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/

Verification:

```
DECLARE @PageSize int 
SET @PageSize = 5


;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 as pagenum 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT pagenum+1 AS pagenum 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE CTE.pagenum < 100
)
SELECT 
     pagenum
    ,@PageSize * (pagenum - 1) AS StartOFFSETBase0
    --,@PageSize * (pagenum - 1) + @PageSize - 1 AS EndOFFSETBase0
    ,@PageSize * pagenum - 1 AS EndOFFSETBase0 -- Simplified

    ,@PageSize * (pagenum - 1) + 1 AS StartOFFSETBase1
    ,@PageSize * (pagenum - 1) + @PageSize AS EndOFFSETBase1
FROM CTE
```