# Implement paging (skip / take) functionality with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pagination

I have been trying to understand a little bit about how to implement custom paging in SQL, for instance reading [articles like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging).

I have the following query, which works perfectly. But I would like to implement paging with this one.

```
SELECT TOP x PostId FROM ( SELECT PostId, MAX (Datemade) as LastDate
 from dbForumEntry 
 group by PostId ) SubQueryAlias
 order by LastDate desc
```

**What is it I want**

I have forum posts, with related entries. I want to get the posts with the latest added entries, so I can select the recently debated posts.

Now, I want to be able to get the "top 10 to 20 recently active posts", instead of "top 10".

**What have I tried**

I have tried to implement the ROW functions as the one in the article, but really with no luck.

Any ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

In **SQL Server 2012** it is very very easy

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE ... 
 ORDER BY -- this is a MUST there must be ORDER BY statement
-- the paging comes here
OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

If we want to skip ORDER BY we can use

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
  ...
 ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

*(I'd rather mark that as a hack - but it's used, e.g. by NHibernate. To use a wisely picked up column as ORDER BY is preferred way)*

to answer the question:

```
--SQL SERVER 2012
SELECT PostId FROM 
        ( SELECT PostId, MAX (Datemade) as LastDate
            from dbForumEntry 
            group by PostId 
        ) SubQueryAlias
 order by LastDate desc
OFFSET 10 ROWS -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

New key words `offset` and `fetch next` (just following SQL standards) were introduced.

*But I guess, that you are not using **SQL Server 2012**, right*? In previous version it is a bit (little bit) difficult. Here is comparison and examples for all SQL server versions: [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/)

So, this could work in **SQL Server 2008**:

```
-- SQL SERVER 2008
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
SELECT @Start = 10,@End = 20;


;WITH PostCTE AS 
 ( SELECT PostId, MAX (Datemade) as LastDate
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PostId) AS RowNumber
   from dbForumEntry 
   group by PostId 
 )
SELECT PostId, LastDate
FROM PostCTE
WHERE RowNumber > @Start AND RowNumber <= @End
ORDER BY PostId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a really good answer!

Only question about the sql 2008 one. I want the ORDER BY to happen before the WHERE, as it currently will sort the subset, but we want to select something from the whole set ... Any ideas? :)

Once again, thanks

Comment: If I do understand you correctly, you'd like to sort by LastDate, right? then we can change the OVER() clause this way: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY **MAX(Datemade) desc**). *And remove last ORDER BY PostId*. Now the CTE should be sorted 'sooner' as needed. correct?

Comment: Thank you this helped, a note about 2012 sample, order by is mandatory, I was trying this without order by clause and got error "incorrect syntax" had no idea what was wrong until I look into MSDN syntax and learned that order by is mandatory.

Comment: Is the first row 1 or 0? Should the WHERE be `WHERE RowNumber >= @Start AND RowNumber < @End` to get the first 1000 rows if `@Start` is 0 and `@End` is 1000?

Comment: @CWSpear, well you can try that on your own... but @start = 0 will take the first row and @end = 1000 will mean to take 1000 rows per that page. Check the WHERE clause I used: `WHERE RowNumber > @Start AND RowNumber <= @End`

Comment: Right... that's what I was asking. If it starts counting row numbers at 1 or at 0... but according to what you said, it starts counting at 1.

Comment: I'm a Postgres man myself, this is for an Enterprise client that is _very_ resistant to change/upgrades. _But_, in this case, they _are_ moving to Postgres (decision made before I even came on) and so this is for an export-with-transformations type thing from the old SQL Sever 2008. After this, I swear, no more SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @RadimKöhler  I have read a bit about paging and offset seems to be bad to use. Because SQL will still fetch everything from disk. Can you show a solution not using offset?

Answer (score 19):

In order to do this in SQL Server, you must order the query by a column, so you can specify the rows you want.

Example:

```
select * from table order by [some_column] 
offset 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 rows only
```

And you can't use the "TOP" keyword when doing this.

You can learn more here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 15):

```
OFFSET     10 ROWS       -- skip 10 rows
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

use this in the end of your select syntax. =)

Answer (score 12):

**SQL 2008**

Radim Köhler's answer works, but here is a shorter version:

```
select top 20 * from
(
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnid) AS ROW_NUM
from tablename
) x
where ROW_NUM>10
```

Source: https://forums.asp.net/post/4033909.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use **nested query** for pagination as follow:

Paging from 4 Row to 8 Row where **CustomerId** is **primary key**.

```
SELECT Top 5 * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany' AND CustomerId Not in (SELECT Top 3 CustomerID FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany' order by city) 
order by city;
```

Answer (score -1):

The fix is to modify your EDMX file, using the XML editor, and change the value of **ProviderManifestToken** from **2012** to **2008**. I found that on line 7 in my EDMX file. After saving that change, the paging SQL will be generated using the “old”, SQL Server 2008 compatible syntax.

*My apologies for posting an answer on this very old thread. Posting it for the people like me, I solved this issue today.*

Comment: I don't think this belongs here.  The question is regarding a SQL Server query, while you are explaining how to modify a Visual Studio generated file to work with older SQL Server instances.