# nhibernate take skip not taking as much as it should

Tags: nhibernate

I have this code

```
var items = query.Skip(0).Take(25).List();
```

what I want is that I get 25 entrance from my list(list got 402 entrance).
I never got 25 entrance after this call. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.Take()` and `.Skip()` is at DB side (e.g. on SQL Server - [Implement paging (skip / take) functionality with this query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13220743/1679310)) converted into something like this

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE ... 
 ORDER BY 
OFFSET      0 ROWS       -- skip  0 rows
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY; -- take 25 rows
```

And that would always work if our **`query`** is about one TABLE *(no JOIN)*. I.e. that many rows will result in that many C# items in the result list

But if a query would use JOIN, **joining some collection**, we would still get 25 rows on DB side..

```
parent_id, child_id
        1,       10      
        1,       11      
        2,       12      
        2,       13      
        ...
        -- 25 rows
```

But these would result in less root entities (see parent 1 and 2 has 4 rows). These will, during transformation, be simply converted in just few parents with very uncertain amount of items in collection

My suggestion would be:

> do not join collection when paging is needed. NEVER. Always page on joins related to **`star schema`** (many-to-one)