SSRS Merge row if same values
I have a report to develop like below result, the column 'Group' beside Department has the result that I expected, but in the wrong position, as I am not able to add the grouping behind the 'Desc' Column. If I add the 'Group' behind the 'Desc', the result is not my expected (not able to merge if it is same value for different rows) but the position is what I want.


Why must SSRS grouping follow from left to right? Can we create multiple parents group in a table?

You cannot have groups at both the start and end, you can only have them at one end. The closest you can get it to set the HideDuplicates property of your last group column to whatever you "Group" rowgroup is called (it will be available in the property drop down list). You can also hide the border is the previous value is the same but that's trickier. It will not centre the text though, it will appear in the top row of each group. See this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867768

In some cases you can workaround by using nested tables (I would prefer Alans suggestion if horizontal alignment is optional)
For grouping Group add a second column left (inside group).
Add two tables, one with detail headers and one with detail data.

Now drag and drop the tables inside the main table

Running the report will have the Group values at the last column

