# Pagination from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, pagination, keyset-pagination

I have two tables with the following schema:

- `Table A`: `ColumnA, UserId,` ... - rest of the schema omitted for brevity
- `Table B`: `ColumnB, UserId,` ... - rest of the schema omitted for brevity

The tables can have duplicate values between them. For e.g - Table A row `(<some-columnA-value>, 1, ...)` and Table B row `(<some-columnB-value>, 1, ...)`, 1 being the UserId.

Now, I have an API which is used to fetch all the `UserId` values from both tables. With increasing data, I want to now use pagination for this API and would like to modify the queries accordingly. There should also not be any duplicates over the pages or within a page.

How do I achieve this? Also a requirement is that I need to use keyset pagination rather than offset pagination since offset pagination gets slower as and when the offset increases.

So far, I have thought of using indexed views since there is only 1 column that I require to fetch but since the data keeps changing quite frequently and in large volumes, the overhead of maintaining the indexed view is not optimal.

Table A:

| Column A | UserId |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 2 |
| z | 3 |
| w | 4 |

Table B:

| Column B | UserId |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 5 |
| d | 6 |

Result (if no page size):

| UserId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Result (if page size 3)

Page 1

| UserId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Page 2

| UserId |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Comment: Some sample data and expected inputs/outputs would be useful here.

Comment: Added sample data and expected result set. Also assume all relevant indexes are added.

Comment: Do you not want to include any `Column A` or `Column B` data in your results? If not, the data can be combined using a `UNION` - `SELECT A.UserId FROM TableA A UNION SELECT B.UserId FROM TableB B`.  The UNION will eliminate duplicates. Once you have that, the paging can be done by adding `ORDER BY UserId OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNum - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wje3jrgE). See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220743/implement-paging-skip-take-functionality-with-this-query).

Comment: I don't want columnA or columnB. Also, I need keyset pagination and not offset pagination as your approach recommends. The order of data can be in O(million). Offset pagination perf degrades with offset values.

Comment: If `TableA` and `TableB` are *wide* tables (lots of columns) it may pay to create indexes for just `UserId` on each, even if already the PK or the leading column of another index. SQL server can read in and merge (union) a few megabytes of compact index data pretty quickly. The alternative is to read in all UserId values once and cache the data - either in your application or in some application-managed pseudo-temporary SQL table structure. The data might be cached as a numbered list of UserId values, or as a numbered page list with UserId ranges. (Cached data may become stale though.)

Comment: Or perhaps `SELECT TOP (@PageSize) UserId FROM (SELECT TOP (@PageSize) UserId FROM TableA WHERE UserId > @PriorUserId ORDER BY UserId UNION SELECT TOP (@PageSize) UserId FROM TableB WHERE UserId > @PriorUserId ORDER BY UserId) U ORDER BY UserId`. This assumes you already have the prior page max UserId - `@PriorUserId`.  It will select the next `@PageSize` UserIds separately (and efficiently) from each table, union them, and again apply an ordered `TOP (@PageSize)` filter to get the final page contents.

Comment: Or a hybrid: Skipping ahead from page `@PriorPage` to `@SelectedPage` could be achieved by replacing the inner `TOP (@PageSize)` with `TOP (@PageSize * (@SelectedPage - @PriorPage))` and replacing the outer `TOP (@PageSize)` with `OFFSET @PageSize * (@SelectedPage - @PriorPage - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY`.  Paging backwards could also be achieved with a second query that applied similar logic to descending UserIds. Not perfect, but better than starting from page 1 every time.

Comment: ***I don't want to be the only one responding here, as I have only limited paged-query experience. Does anyone else have any suggestions?***

Comment: The UserId is part of the clustered index in both the tables. The clustered indices are (ColumnA, UserId) and (ColumnB, UserId)  for both the tables respectively.

Comment: I have to try your suggestions out to be able to respond whether I am actually getting the intended result set. Will respond once done. Can ROW_NUMBER() be of help here?

Comment: The whole design is kinda weird. Don't you have a User table? Or what's the revelance of the ColumnA, ColumnB, if they don't always exists in both tables, you can't search on them i guess.

Comment: No `ROW_NUMBER` is essentially the same as paging using `OFFSET` with the even bigger downside that the whole set needs to be read.

Comment: @TN `OFFSET` is not relevant for keyset pagination. It's highly inefficient, requiring reading all rows in the whole table up to where you need to go.

Comment: @KaustabhKakoty - I do not think having clustered indexes on  (ColumnA, UserId) and (ColumnB, UserId) is sufficient to support efficient UserId seeks because UserId is not the first column. You will need indexes that place UserId first.

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes. I figured that out after Kaustabh Kakoty responded to my first comment. (I hadn't read the original post closely enough.) I believe the approach outlined in my 19:59:22Z "Or perhaps" post is the closest thing you can get to a keyset lookup when pulling from two sources unioned together. I would expect that each table reference should be an index seek extracting at most `@PageSize` rows. Up to half of the combined result is then discarded by the final `TOP (@PageSize)` - a relatively small price. The "Or a hybrid" would allow more then just single page forward navigation.

Comment: @TN If you look at my answer below, you'll see the idea is to keep the union in the correct order using a Merge Union/Concatenation, then do the `TOP` afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mention in [my canonical post on **Keyset Pagination**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997) (paging by key), the base query needs to be efficient.

The key (sic) in your case, is to use a *Merge Union*, group up by ID, and then take the top 3. This means that the grouping is over an already sorted set, and can use a *Stream Aggregation*.

So first `UNION ALL` the tables together, then `GROUP BY UserId` the final result and take `TOP (3)`.

```sql
SELECT TOP (3)
  t.UserId
FROM (
    SELECT a.UserId
    FROM TableA a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.UserId
    FROM TableB b
) t
GROUP BY t.UserId
ORDER BY UserId;
```

Final query plan is nice and neat. Note that the union is keeping the ordering correct for the later stages.

[image]

As I mention, you need to keep the previous highest ID value, and pass it in to the next query. Put it into both halves of the union.

```sql
SELECT TOP (3)
  t.UserId
FROM (
    SELECT a.UserId
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.UserId > @previousId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.UserId
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE b.UserId > @previousId
) t
GROUP BY t.UserId
ORDER BY UserId;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xq0aTWH6)

Comment: Nice answer. I did not realize that SQL Server would intelligently propagate the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` down to the subqueries. This will also work with a plain old `UNION` (no ALL), which eliminates the need for the `GROUP BY`.  I made some changes to your fiddle changing the PK to be compound, and adding a separate index for UserId. I also added 10000 more rows and changed the @previousId. Also added the plain UNION version and my earlier post. All queries ran index seeks pulling just 2 or 3 rows from each table. Updated fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/s9usLFUP).

Comment: You need to be careful with `UNION`, as it implies `DISTINCT` which means it may group differently than what you intended. Also the extra `TOP` is not necessary, assuming you can get a fully non-blocking plan. If the inner queries do some kind of hash or sort then you are right that you must add `TOP` to the inside.

Comment: Note for @KaustabhKakoty - Having a PK or index with UserId *first* is essential. If the UserId indexes are dropped leaving only the (ColumnA, UserId) and (ColumnA, UserId) PKs, the query reverts to all out clustered index scans. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CpHJaHN-)

Comment: Yes correct. I stress this very much in my other post: the query *needs* to have an efficient access method by that key, and the key must be unique.

Comment: Using `set statistics xml on` in a fiddle to show the execution plan was something I hadn't seen before. I learned something new today (actually several things).

Comment: @Charlieface tried out your solution on my dataset and checked the fiddle as well. Can confirm that it is working as expected. I've added NCI to the userId column in both tables and its doing index seek now which should be more performant

Comment: @Charlieface I was trying to add some filter conditions on the two parts of the UNIONs by adding ColumnA = 'somevalue' and ColumnB = 'somevalue'. The query plan deteriorates significantly.

Comment: @Charlieface will the order of the UNION ALL matter? putting tableA first or tableB first?

Comment: Generally `UNION ALL` is executed in the order they are written, but that shouldn't matter, as both need to be read. You need to make sure the results are presorted to get the Merg Union to work properly. As mentioned many times, the base query *must* be efficient, so you need to have the correct indexes in place to get both the filering and ordering without scanning the base table. For such a query, I would expect an index `(ColumnA, ColumnB, UserID)` possibly also `INCLUDE` other columns if you also want to select those. You need this index on both tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to only need to retrieve pages in ascending sequence, Charlieface's answer is the *Keyset Pagination* solution that you want.

However, if you also have a need to support arbitrary navigation, the following extension of the *Keyset Pagination* technique will allow you to efficiently navigate the first, next, prior, and same page as previously accessed, and will also (at an increased cost) allow navigation to an arbitrary page.

In both cases, having an index or primary key with `UserId` as the **first column** is essential to an efficient execution using an index seek.

The code below contains separate queries to support the following scenarios:

- First page - Selects the first @PageSize rows.
- Next page - Selects the next @PageSize rows above the last maximum key value.
- Prior page - Selects the previous @PageSize rows before the last minimum key.
- Same page - Selects @PageSize rows at or above the last minimum key value.
- Skip ahead N pages - Scans the next N * @PageSize rows above the last maximum key value, selecting only the last @PageSize rows.
- Skip back N pages - Scans the prior N * @PageSize rows before the last minimum key value, selecting only the last (lowest) @PageSize rows.
- Initial retrieval of page N - Scans the first N * @PageSize rows, selecting only the last @PageSize rows.

The last three operations would have an increased cost proportional to the number of pages skipped, but this is unavoidable without some kind of numbered key index or other.

Logic is also present to seek from the start if the requested page number is less than half the previous page number, since that would involve skipping fewer rows. Seek from start is also the fallback if any "prior" data values are unavailable (null) or invalid.

```
-- Procedure to retrieve paged UserIds using modified Keyset Pagination
-- Optimally supports first, next, prior, and same page retrieval.
-- Arbitrary page navigation minimizes discarded row retrieval.
-- Efficient execution depends on key being the first indexed column of some index.
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPagedUserIdsExtended
    @PageSize INT,
    @PageNumber INT,
    @PreviousPageNumber INT = NULL,
    @PreviousMinUserId INT = NULL,
    @PreviousMaxUserId INT = NULL
AS

DECLARE @Offset INT
  
IF (@PageNumber IS NULL
    OR @PageNumber <= 0
    OR @PageSize IS NULL
    OR @PageSize <= 0
)
BEGIN
    -- Invalid - Return empty result
    SELECT 0 AS UserId
END
  
ELSE IF (@PageNumber = 1
         OR @PreviousPageNumber IS NULL
         OR @PreviousPageNumber <= 0
         OR (@PreviousMinUserId IS NULL AND @PageNumber < @PreviousPageNumber)
         OR (@PreviousMaxUserId IS NULL AND @PageNumber >= @PreviousPageNumber)
         OR @PageNumber < @PreviousPageNumber / 2 -- Quicker to seek from start
)
BEGIN
    -- Seek relative to start
    SET @Offset = @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1)

    SELECT U.UserId
    FROM (
        SELECT A.UserId
        FROM TableA A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT B.UserId
        FROM TableB B
    ) U
    GROUP BY U.UserId
    ORDER BY U.UserId
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END

ELSE IF (@PageNumber = @PreviousPageNumber)
BEGIN
    -- Same page seek forward
    SET @Offset = 0

    SELECT U.UserId
    FROM (
        SELECT A.UserId
        FROM TableA A
        WHERE A.UserId >= @PreviousMinUserId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT B.UserId
        FROM TableB B
        WHERE B.UserId >= @PreviousMinUserId
    ) U
    GROUP BY U.UserId
    ORDER BY U.UserId
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END

ELSE IF (@PageNumber > @PreviousPageNumber)
BEGIN
    -- Seek forward 1 or more pages
    SET @Offset = @PageSize * (@PageNumber - @PreviousPageNumber - 1)

    SELECT U.UserId
    FROM (
        SELECT A.UserId
        FROM TableA A
        WHERE A.UserId > @PreviousMaxUserId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT B.UserId
        FROM TableB B
        WHERE B.UserId > @PreviousMaxUserId
    ) U
    GROUP BY U.UserId
    ORDER BY U.UserId
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END

ELSE IF (@PageNumber < @PreviousPageNumber)
BEGIN
    -- Seek backwards 1 or more pages
    SET @Offset = @PageSize * (@PreviousPageNumber - @PageNumber - 1)

    SELECT U.UserId
    FROM (
        SELECT U.UserId
        FROM (
            SELECT A.UserId
            FROM TableA A
            WHERE A.UserId < @PreviousMinUserId
            UNION ALL
            SELECT B.UserId
            FROM TableB B
            WHERE B.UserId < @PreviousMinUserId
        ) U
        GROUP BY U.UserId
        ORDER BY U.UserId DESC
        OFFSET @Offset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    ) U
    ORDER BY U.UserId -- Reorder ascending
END

-- End of procedure
```

One slight difference from Charlieface's query is that the above uses a plain `UNION` (with no ALL), which de-dups the results, eliminating the need for `GROUP BY`. As far as I can tell, the execution plans and results are the same.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GDF2q5Zu) for a demo that shows the results and execution plans for a variety of page seeks. For the purposes of the demo, the result queries were modified to also return some additional information to be displayed in the test results.

Note that if you hover over the Index Seek operations to view statistics, you can see that the "Actual Number of Rows" for each index seek is proportional to the page size * page navigation distance.

Also note that the single-page first, next, and prior navigation queries will effectively retrieve results using `... OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY`, which produces the same execution plan as `TOP (@PageSize)` with no offset.