# Is this a good way to get second row of the result?

Tags: t-sql

In my sample code it certainly worked, but I don't know if that's guaranteed in general. Help?

```
DECLARE @selectedId int

DECLARE @t TABLE(id int)
INSERT INTO @t(id) 
VALUES (1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)

-- FIRST ROW
SELECT TOP 1 @selectedId = id from @t ORDER BY id
SELECT @selectedId -- (good) expected 1, actual 1

-- SECOND ROW
SELECT TOP 2 @selectedId = id from @t ORDER BY id
SELECT @selectedId -- (good) expected 2 actual 2
```

Comment: top returns the number of rows - why not just do one select?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement paging (skip / take) functionality with this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220743/implement-paging-skip-take-functionality-with-this-query)

Answer (score 2):

*If* I am guessing correctly, you are asking for alternatives to getting the 2nd id. Different methods would be to use a CTE/derived table and `ROW_NUMBER` or use `OFFSET ... FETCH`.

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RN
    FROM @t)
SELECT id
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 2;

SELECT id
FROM @t
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

As for if the the results you have are guaranteed, it is if your `ORDER BY` is deterministic. For the sample data you've given us, it is, but that's because you only have one column.