# Custom paging using Data Column with gap in Records

Tags: c#, sql-server, pagination, ado.net, dapper

For implementing a custom paging solution using `C#, ADO.Net`, with SQL Server as database, let us assume following details:

```
Total Records = 1000
Page Size = 100
```

This would mean there are `10 pages`, I use a query as follows:

`Min and Max Id (Primary Key)` are fetched using scalar Queries:

```
Select Min(Id), Max(Id) from Table;

Select * from Table where Id >= (Min Record) and Id < (Max Record)
```

Here for every transaction, `Min and Max Record Value` is incremented by Page Size, till the point Max Record reach or exceed the Actual Max value.

This solution works fine for an auto increment / identity column, which have continuous values, but let's assume the column used has gap in values, though they can still be ordered, like `1000 values` are between `Min = 1 and Max = 3000`.

- I have following possible work around, one suggested in following SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758186/how-to-get-n-rows-starting-from-row-m-from-sorted-table-in-t-sql), where an extra `RowId column` is used to achieve the same.
- Other options would be opening a Reader and read a record for given Page, create a List and thus fetch a Page

What I ideally want is executing a `Top <PageSize>` sql query, where it is executed from a pre-defined row or value that I suggest, instead of beginning, thus I would avoid creating an extra column, I can work with disconnected architecture, no Reader is required.

Any suggestion or pointer, please let me know if a clarification is required, for any detail in the question

Comment: That's there in the SO link posted in the question, but I want to avoid the extra column creation. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758186/how-to-get-n-rows-starting-from-row-m-from-sorted-table-in-t-sql

Comment: You can use this solution but add an extra `SELECT` on top to exclude the new column if it is that much undesirable.

Comment: @AkaGuymelef as the link above suggest do I also need an inner join between derived and parent table, does that help performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by any chance you are using Sql Server 2012 onwards, you can use

> Fetch and Offset

e.g.

```
-- Variable to hold the offset value
Declare @RowSkip As int
-- Variable to hold the fetch value
Declare @RowFetch As int

--Set the value of rows to skip
 Set @RowSkip = 20000
--Set the value of rows to fetch
 Set @RowFetch = 50000

Select *
From dbo.tblSample 
Order by (Select 1)  
Offset @RowSkip Row 
Fetch  Next @RowFetch Rows Only;
```

Please refer : [Usage 1: Server Side Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162620/An-Introduction-to-Sql-Code-Name-Denali-Part-II#3.3) for more details

Comment: Thanks this looks fairly promising

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) function in a [common table expression(CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
    t.*, 
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.ID)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT ID, Col2, Col3, ...
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN >= (@pageIndedx * @pageSize) AND RN <= (@pageIndedx * @pageSize) + @pageSize
```

Comment: Aware of this solution, it is there in the SO link posted, trying to figure out a way to avoid an extra column added as part of CTE

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: you don't need to select all columns including the row-number column, just replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT allcolumnsfromtable`.

Comment: But wouldn't the CTE which is a run time feature have a performance impact for a table which have millions of records, it is getting executed at run time

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: what means "it is a runtime feauture", it's similar to a view/subquery in the database. There's no performance impact. It will use indexes as every sql query. If you self-join a cte with itself you might have a performance impact but not in this case.

Comment: Got it thanks, let me see if someone can help with a solution without using Row_Number()

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: note that i've edited my answer to provide a query where you have to provide two parameters, the current pageindex and the pagesize.