# Dynamic Paging in MVC4 ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been using this example for my code.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
My issue is in controller I simply cannot afford to make a call to database 1000 times if there are 1000 pages. How can i store my list somewhere in controller or model and use that when calling this students has to be stored somewhere.

```
return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you can't afford one DB call per request?

Comment: Then store it in a list and call `cachedList.Skip(n).Take(m)`.

Comment: I can afford to make one call and save it as List somewhere and then use that list for paging but everytime i switch pages i cannot make database calls. Yes How can i stored cachedList. Is it possible to store in controller or model?

Comment: You can use the `Session["key"]` store.

Comment: Thank you I can store it in session and reuse it. :)

Comment: Now i am using Session to store around 7 million records and whenever i make a request for 7 million session expires or becomes null and nothing is stored.

Comment: So the trade-off you need to make is memory usage versus database calls. You can also consider sending the entire set to the client and paginate with javascript in the browser.

Comment: There's critical information you are leaving out here if you need to cache 7M records. Why can't the original query be more selective? Perhaps you should look to [optimize your original query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758186/how-to-get-n-rows-starting-from-row-m-from-sorted-table-in-t-sql)?

Comment: I have tried paginating using javascript on client but to send all data to client takes more than 30 minutes (considering 7 Million Records) also query runs in around 15 seconds rest is sending that data to page. When i select range for more than 70K records and I switch page it shows this error:This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet. But i am not even using JSon for return i am sending dataset to partialview only.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: Caching Application Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx)

You need to use caching. Pay careful attention to when you invalidate the cache. If the data updates often enough caching may not actually help much.