# Select database rows in range

Tags: sql, select

I want to select the rows between A and B from a table. The table has at least A rows but it might have less than B rows.
For example if A = 2, B = 5 and the table has 3 rows it should return rows 2 and 3.

How could I get the rows in such a range?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something similar to what's being described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver) SO question.

I.E.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YOUR_ORDERED_FIELD) as row FROM YOUR_TABLE
 ) a WHERE row > 5 and row <= 10
```

Where A = 5 and B = 10 in your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY ordercol) AS 'rank'
FROM table
where rank between @a and @b
```