# How I can limit result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have table containing data for users, I need to get only last 2 users after first user ex

```
id-username
1-john
2-fredrek
3-sara
4-sarah
```

I need to get `fredrek, sara` - how do I do this in SQL Server ??

I know to do that with MySQL I use LIMIT1,2 but with SQL Server I can't

Comment: same thing already discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 2):

To avoid 2 x TOP you can use ROW_NUMBER (note: you can't use ROW_NUMBER output directly in the WHERE clause of a single statement )

```
;WITH cRN AS
(
  SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn,
     username
  FROM
     mytable
)
SELECT username
FROM cRN
WHERE rn BETWEEN 2 AND 3
```

Comment: This is the easy solution. There is no LIMIT feature in SQL Server (until next version).

Comment: and i can use this way with php mssql_query();

Answer (score 1):

You can use TOP, restricting in the WEHRE clause, not to take the first register

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TOP in T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 2 FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server, [you can use the TOP command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a dual query:

```
   select * from ( select top 10 * from (
    select top 20 * from table_name order by 1 asc 
    ) as tb_name order by 1 desc
    ) as tb_name_last 
    order by whathever;
```