# MSSQL TOP (LIMIT) operation with extra WHERE and ORDER BY clauses

Tags: php, sql-server, limit

I'm confused when first met with the problem of using LIMIT clause in MSSQL. Can't get it how to make the pagination script work.

I want to use LIMIT clause with extra WHERE and ORDERY BY conditions. Any help is welcome!

This is my MySQL query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FLD_NAME, FLD_AGE FROM TBL_USERS WHERE FLAG='1' ORDER BY FLD_AGE DESC LIMIT 0,50");

//rows_per_page = 50;
```

How can I convert this MySQL query to the MSSQL query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See duplicate answered question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 5):

For full pagination, you can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function somewhat like:

```
select * from 
(select Row_Number() over ( ORDER BY FLD_AGE DESC ) as RowIndex, FLD_NAME, FLD_AGE FROM    
TBL_USERS WHERE FLAG='1') as pager    Where pager.RowIndex >= 10 and pager.RowIndex < 40
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP(50) FLD_NAME, FLD_AGE FROM TBL_USERS WHERE FLAG='1' ORDER BY FLD_AGE DESC
```

For full pagination sample check Google!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 50 FLD_NAME,FLD_AGE
FROM TBL_USERS
WHERE FLAG='1'
ORDER BY FLD_AGE DESC;
```

For more information, visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)  and [MSDN again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738522.aspx)