# MySQL query performance improvement?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL query similar to:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `col3` = "stuff"
ORDER BY `hour_col` DESC, `minute_col` DESC, `second_col` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But since I only need the first row that is returned it seems like there might be a more efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

Also, the hour, minute, and second columns need to remain separate columns (in other words I cant store them as a single Time datatype).

Comment: What is inefficient about this? Btw, you can do just `LIMIT 1`. When you specify one argument to `LIMIT`, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set.

Comment: I think just doing the order by makes it seem like it would be inefficient since I only need the one row.

Comment: If you don't do the `ORDER BY` there's no guarantee you'll always get the same row. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6314893/1086938

Comment: Correct. I'm really just seeing if anyone thinks there is a better way to get the same result.

Comment: Where are the indexes? The Explain plan? Why is the data not normalized?

Comment: _“Also, the hour, minute, and second columns need to remain separate columns (in other words I cant store them as a single Time datatype)”_ – _why_ not?

Comment: It's a requirement that I don't have control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe given your limitations this can be made any more efficient outside of putting a composite index across col_3, hour_col, minute_col, second_col, col1, col2.

```
 CREATE INDEX covering_index 
        ON mytable (col_3, hour_col, minute_col,second_col, col1, col2);
```

This index will help avoid point lookup in the main table is it sorts and returns the values you need.