# ActiveRecord - Getting the 5th-10th record from the database

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, sinatra

I was quite curious to see how one could get the records from n to kth. I don't know if i missed it or not, but going through the docs didn't provide favorable to me.

I'm not saying i want the records where id is between 5 - 10, but the records between 5 - 10. How does one go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`limit` and `offset`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset):

```
Client.order("id ASC").limit(5).offset(5)
```

Comment: You should also explicitly sort: `Client.order("id ASC").limit(5).offset(5)` The ordering may sometimes be correct without it but that's not guaranteed by e.g. Postgres. ([See docs.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html)) [Seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314879/does-limit-offset-length-require-order-by-for-pagination) the same applies to MySQL.