# MySQL's LIMIT in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I am trying to understand the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server) question.

The MySQL code that I wish to use in SQL Server is this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE city_id=1 ORDER BY datejoined ASC LIMIT 20,10;
```

Is there a simpler solution I could use?

(obviously '20' in the code above is a parameter but I am executing this query from application code so I am able to just build the string like `...LIMIT " + ((page * 10) - 10) + ",10;";`. Ie. no need for tsql parameter passing syntax.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver

Comment: Unless you wait for SQL Server Denali, the solution you are linking is the best way to do pagination

Answer (score 0):

```
I am trying to understand the solution to this question
```

ROWNUMBER() is a function, it will simply assign a row number to every row selected.

consider it like this, first of all ur result will be selected filtered by where clause criteris, then one additional column will be added to your result, and this additional column will only have numbering 1,2,3....so on.

```
LIMIT 

clause tells MYSQL to limit the number of rows returned. Same u can achieved using RowNumber() function, as now row number have been assigned to every row, u can tell SqlServer in where clause that only fethched rows with RowNumber less than 10. (u will have to use nested query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would look like this

```
select * from ( select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by datejoined) _ROW_NUMBER from users where city_id = 1 ) a where _ROW_NUMBER between 20 and 30
```