# SQL - Limit results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, limit

I was wondering if you could do something like this is Microsoft SQL Server 2k8 R2

Say I have a query which returns 100 rows of data.

Is their a way I can pass in some variables for example @lower_limit and @upper_limit.

Then I want the query to record the rows between the lower and upper limit

For example:

```
@lower_limit = 5
@upper_limt  10
```

Would return me rows 5 - 10 from the 100 records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIMIT 10..20 in sqlserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a ROW_NUMBER() over your result set and then use the `BETWEEN` statement to limit the rows.

A contrived example:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
       ,YourColumn
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    data
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

**EDIT:** For standard paging, here's exactly the technique I use in all the applications I develop:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = /* The page number you want */
DECLARE @PageSize int = /* The number of records per page */
WITH paged AS
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [OrderByColumns]) AS RowNum
        ,*
    FROM
        [YourSource]
)
SELECT 
     [Column1]
    ,[Column2]
    ,...
FROM 
    paged
WHERE 
    RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNumber * @PageSize
ORDER BY 
    [OrderByColumns] -- Same as used in ROW_NUMBER()
```

Comment: +1 Definitely! I created [a post](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2008/08/painful-sql-server-pagination.html) about this a while ago.

Comment: That is unreal Cory, many thanks, so much better than the way the dude before me here implemented the pagination for this site.
He was calling the SP everytime and then limiting what shows in the code.

Comment: @user1052764: I edited my answer to show you a full technique for paging that I use.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
(
    select *, row_number() over(order by someColToOrderBy) RowNum
    from yourTable
) a
where RowNum between @lower_limit and @uppder_limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  ID, Foo, Bar
FROM    (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row, ID, Foo, Bar 
            FROM SomeTable
        ) 
        tmp
WHERE   Row >= @RowRangeStart AND Row <= @RowRangeEnd
```