# Visual Web Developer 2010 SQL return single row

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, row

I am trying to create a  simple table and chart for my data but i cannot limit the rows in which it displays.

How can you do this, I have searched and found nothing.

My chart now has 420 bars of data haha it looks ridiculous, I need to limit the rows.

I have paginated my other table to display 5 rows per page but that only masks it.

To get the data I have gone the route of dragging over SQLdatasource tool and built my query that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is limit the results coming back from your query.  Depending on your backend:

```
SELECT * FROM  MyTable LIMIT x;
```

or

```
SELECT TOP x FROM MyTable...
```

Where x is the number of results you want returned from your query.

If neither of those work for you (SQL Server may not, for instance), check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/971994/183624) on a similar question.

Comment: the LIMIT is what im used to (im a mysql boy). 

the TOP * worked a treat and sorted me out, just a whole day wasted thats all. Thankyou!