# How to get only first result in tables join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT  

    Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
    Sprav_093.Name as Road_Wear

FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Driveway_Pavement ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Driveway_Pavement.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Sprav_093 ON Driveway_Pavement.Kod_Spr093 = Sprav_093.Kod_Spr
```

Is works fine. There are several row with same `Segment_ID` in table `Driveway_Pavement`. So i want get just first of this rows. How can i do it?

Comment: add `LIMIT 1` to the end? [SQL Limit/Top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver)

Comment: What makes one of those rows to be first than the other?, what is the criteria?

Comment: use `TOP 1` for SQL-Server, SQL Server doesn't support `LIMIT`

Comment: @rs: i get syntax error on `TOP`.

Comment: @KliverMax, correct syntax is `SELECT TOP 1 columnnames`

Comment: @rs: if i write `SELECT TOP 1 Segment_ID.Segment_ID` i get error anyway(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return one row for each segment id, do this

```
;WITh CTE AS (
SELECT  

    Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
    Sprav_093.Name as Road_Wear,
    CASE WHEN Sprav_093.Name IS NOT NULL THEN 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Segment_ID.Segment_ID 
                       ORDER BY Sprav_093.Name//or date column) 
    ELSE 1 END rn

FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Driveway_Pavement ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Driveway_Pavement.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Sprav_093 ON Driveway_Pavement.Kod_Spr093 = Sprav_093.Kod_Spr
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Yeah its work. But i lost some rows. I have 207 rows in `Segment_ID` but query return 147.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply a MAX function to both selected fields

Comment: Max may not work here.  If for instance the rows were 1, 20 and 2, 10 applying max to both rows gives you 2, 20.  This means you now have part of two different rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT  

    Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
    Sprav_093.Name as Road_Wear

FROM dbo.Road
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Segment_ID.Segment_ID
    FROM Segment_ID
    WHERE Segment_ID.Road_ID = Road.Road_ID
) Segment_ID  
LEFT JOIN Driveway_Pavement ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Driveway_Pavement.Segment_ID
LEFT JOIN Sprav_093 ON Driveway_Pavement.Kod_Spr093 = Sprav_093.Kod_Spr
```

You can add an `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT` inside of the `OUTER APPLY` if you want a specific "first" row.