# How to get the first rows after order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

How can I get only the first few rows,
After I performed order by to a table?

In SQL 2012, let's say I have a table:

```
 ----------------------
| Sales | ProductType |
 ----------------------
120     | Foodstuff
100     | Electronic
200     | Mobile
```

Now the problem is:
I select with order by Sales DESC

and I only want to get 2 rows.

Comment: What database platform is this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver  for limiting in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use the limit clause.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  ORDER BY sales DESC
  LIMIT n;
```

Where n is the number of rows you want to select