# MYSQL Query have only upto LIMIT, How can I modify the query into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to convert the query FROM `MYSQL` TO `MSSQL`.
MYSQL QUERY:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.tc_id 
 FROM mnrelease_details a, 
     tc_details b 
 WHERE a.tc_id=b.tc_name 
       AND tester IS NULL 
       AND release_name=? 
       AND tenv_id=? 
       AND env_id=? 
       AND tst_type=? AND a.project=b.project 
       AND a.project=? 
 ORDER BY tc_priority LIMIT"
```

MSSQL QUERY:

```
   SELECT * 
   from 
      (
        select 
           DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (ORDER BY  b.tc_priority ) AS row, 
           a.tc_id 
      from 
        release_details a, 
        tc_details b 
    where 
        a.tc_id=b.tc_name 
        and tst_system is null 
        and release_name='sdkfei' 
        and tenv_id='32' 
        and env_id='32' 
        and tst_type='21' 
        and b.autotech='ITL' 
        and a.project=b.project 
        and a.project='JupiterQA' 
      and depclosed=1) AS tab12 
  WHERE 
    row BETWEEN
```

If I've limit `x`,`y` in MYSQL means I will use `BETWEEN` `x` and `y` in MSSQL.
But `x`,`y` is dynamically append when my java code is running.
The Query have only upto `LIMIT` in MYSQL, then how can I modify the query into MSSQL.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically append when code is running ?

Comment: Can you just have that as a stored procedure and have 2 variables, where row >= @lowerLimit and row < @upperLimit?

Comment: In MySQL,dynamically append limit values @ end of the query. EX: LIMIT 3,5

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIMIT 10..20 in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server)