# Query for select 2nd row of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL statement that yeilds something like this:

```
Amounts
$101.45
$1000.56
$20978.44
$2.98
```

The SQL that got me this is:

```
select CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT
from V_Rpt
where ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '100'
and CHANGE_TYPE_CODE = 2
order by TRAN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER desc
```

How can I structure my statement so that it only returns the second value in this column?  Basically, something like "select the 2nd in a column from..."  The value will change all the time but it will always be the value after the top one.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, in case it matters.  And, this will eventually go into MS Access 2007 as a pass-through query.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify by providing more data and expected result. Also, what determines 2nd? Does your query only return rows of dates?

Comment: Unless you `order by` something, there is no inherent notion of row ordering. Your best bet would be to use a `rank` function of some kind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIMIT 10..20 in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server)

Comment: I tried `ROW_NUMBER()` and it did create a column that identified my value as 2, but when I added a where clause to say `and RowNumber = 2`, it gave me an error that I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRAN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER DESC)
    FROM V_Rpt
    WHERE 
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '100'
        AND CHANGE_TYPE_CODE = 2
)
SELECT CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 2
```

*This will return nothing if your query has only 1 row.*

---

Using a SUBQUERY:

```
SELECT
    t.CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TRAN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER DESC)
    FROM V_Rpt
    WHERE 
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '100'
        AND CHANGE_TYPE_CODE = 2
)t
WHERE t.RN = 2
```

Comment: thank you very much, I am trying to learn about CTEs.  I tried what you did and got this error:  `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: oh awesome that worked!!  Do you happen to know if CTEs are allowed in pass-through queries in MS Access?

Comment: Oh, that I dont' know. You could easily convert it a subquery. See updated answer.

Comment: that's killer, thank you for such a swift and helpful response.  I will learn more about CTEs.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` to your query.

```
  select CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT
    from V_Rpt
    where ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '100'
    and CHANGE_TYPE_CODE = 2
    order by TRAN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER desc OFFSET 1 ROW
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

`OFFSET` skip 1 row and return only the next row from the result set.

Comment: the answer above may have taken care of everything but just so you know, this returned an error `Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'` and `Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement`.

Comment: Because that's SQL2012 syntax. The OP asked about SQL2008R2

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name limit 1,1
```

For `limit x,y` `x` is index of start row and `y` is number of lines.

Comment: select CHANGE_EFFECTIVE_AMOUNT
from V_Rpt
where ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '100'
and CHANGE_TYPE_CODE = 2
order by TRAN_SEQUENCE_NUMBER desc limit 1,1

Comment: `Limit` clause is not part of standard SQL nor SQL-SERVER. Even SQL2012 doesn't have this syntax. Use [OFFSET FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) instead in SQL2012

Comment: i was asking myself why the answer is so complicated. I only worked with Mysql and Oracle :p