# I got some values from database dynamically want in whole numbers in C#

Tags: c#, math

I got some values from database dynamically, 34 ,104, 1117
I want for 34 to 40, 104 to 110, and 1120,
Please Help!

Comment: And the usual request follows: Where is your code? Did you try anything to show us?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server

Comment: Also, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devid by 10, use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx), and multiply by 10.