# inner join gives back multiple values

Tags: php, inner-join, sqlsrv

I have products, All of these products have for example. An id, name and price. All of these products are connected in the database like this:

Since I don't have 10 reputation... Here is a link to a picture http://puu.sh/oS95c/b7b5b17427.png

What I want to achieve is to have products that are connected to another product show up on the screen using inner join. However instead of getting the connected items back I get back every item of the right column even if they are not connected.

Here is a link to get a better view of the database: http://puu.sh/oSBF2/1af1ce3751.png

```
$sql = "SELECT   AFBEELDING_KLEIN, PRODUCTNAAM, PRIJS
    FROM PRODUCT
    inner JOIN PRODUCT_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT
    ON PRODUCT.PRODUCTNUMMER=PRODUCT_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT.PRODUCTNUMMER_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT";

$result = sqlsrv_query($db, $sql);
$data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    $big_picture = '<img src="../' . $data["AFBEELDING_KLEIN"] . '"' . 'alt="product">';
    $link = '<a href="../productpaginas/' . $data["PRODUCTNAAM"] . '.php"<p>&nbsp;' . $data["PRODUCTNAAM"] . '</p></a>';
    $price = '<h2>&nbsp; &#8364;' . $data["PRIJS"] . '</h2>';

    echo '<div class="product">';
    echo $big_picture;
    echo $link;
    echo $price;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Why not share the text output you get?  (You can change the prices if you want, or remove the column, but nothing else.)

Comment: Please show the SQL statement used to generate the result in the graphic.

Comment: Which tables do belong to products and which colums are defined for each of those? Best would be showing the table definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you immune to questions and don't provide more information, we can only guess.

You might want a m:n link back to the product table itself.

```
SELECT
  p1.PRODUCTNUMMER, p2.AFBEELDING_KLEIN, p2.PRODUCTNAAM, p2.PRIJS
FROM
  PRODUCT AS p1
INNER JOIN
  PRODUCT_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT AS pgp
ON
  p1.PRODUCTNUMMER = pgp.PRODUCTNUMMER
INNER JOIN
  PRODUCT AS p2
ON
  pgp.PRODUCTNUMMER_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT = p2.PRODUCTNUMMER
;
```

Comment: i am really sorry that i couldn't reply.  here is another link to maybe get a better view on the database http://puu.sh/oSBF2/1af1ce3751.png. want for example

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link there, so other people can find it easily as well. It looks as you wanted some sort of query as I've posted.

Comment: is that i want to get product(s) back based on the relations defined in the table "PRODUCT_GERELATEERD_PRODUCT". For example if you look at the first screenshot : if i am at the page of product 1 i would want to get back the information of product 2 and 3. The query you posted brings me a little closer but now i want to show only the first 2. Thank you for the help

Comment: MS SQL Server should have something similar as the `LIMIT` clause in MySQL. In worst case you would only fetch 2 rows and break the loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server to find a proper solution depending on your server version.