# How Separate result set into few parts in Sql or in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a result set that contains about 800 records, how can I split them into eight parts, which contain 100 records for each column?

Note: for the result set, there is ONLY one column which is that one contains 800 rows, so it seems impossible to get each 100 by using 'select...where ID between 1 and 100'; 'select...where ID between 101 and 200' etc.

Any idea guys? Appreciate it in advance

Comment: Problem solved, could use RowNumber Over function along with either derived table or CTE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIMIT 10..20 in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this?
Just set your limits between the `rownum >=` and the `rownum < 200`

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Table
    WHERE <whatever>
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >= 100
AND RowNum < 200
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of ! :)