# Data from serverside not display

Tags: php, sql-server, server, server-side

hello guys i try data use datatables from serverside (SQL Server) if me use code
my data not found or not availaible. this is my code

```
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
```

please help me

Comment: You could echo your sql string and check the data and grammar.

Comment: I saw `LIMIT` keyword in there. Are you mixing `SQL Server` with `MySQL` ?

Comment: no i'm just use sql server. how can work use sql server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **OFFSET** and **FETCH** in SQL Server [OFFSET FETCH Clause](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx).

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Possible duplicate: [LIMIT 10..20 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server).