# What is the Equivalent syntax of mysql " LIMIT " clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, paging, limit

What is the Equivalent syntax of MySQL " LIMIT " clause in SQL Server . I would like to use it for  doing paging of my results. (want to show records5 to 10 )

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216673/emulate-mysql-limit-clause-in-microsoft-sql-server-2000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement LIMIT with Microsoft SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The closest thing is TOP:

```
Select top 5 * from tablename
```

You can get a range ( rows 5 - 10)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP n * FROM (
    SELECT TOP z columns      -- (z=n+skip)
    FROM tablename
    ORDER BY key ASC
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest to it is `SELECT TOP X` but it is only equivalent to `LIMIT X`.

For `LIMIT X, Y`, there is no direct MS-SQL equivalent (as far as I know). Christian's solution is a good one though.

MSSQL2005 (onwards) has the ROW_NUMBER syntax which might be useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: I really wonder why microsoft doesnt add this feature into sql server?

Answer (score 0):

cont=until desired number is starting to get results
limit=Want to see how many variables

SELECT     TOP (limit) cve_persona
FROM          persona
WHERE      (cve_persona > cont)